# How to publish Umbraco CMS to my localhost?

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, session-state, publishing-site

I published my website in the "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\".
Publish was successful.But when I run it, I confort a problem to web.config

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424"
    sqlConnectionString="Server=defraz-server;Database=Namaad;user id=sa;
    password=;Trusted_Connection=yes" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

[image]
PLEASE HELP ME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened because it looks like you have published your website as a virtual directory of an existing website in your local IIS. The existing site already has a web.config setting for `<sessionState />`.

You can remove this line from your web.config or preferably, set the Umbraco website up as a new website/application in Umbraco.

Comment: I commented sessionState tag.But I received a problem in <authentication mode="Forms"> tag.

Comment: Yes, you will receive an error for each line that is not allowed to be overridden. If you can, as I suggest in my answer, set up the website as a new application or website and not as a virtual directory. If you can't avoid that, then simply keep commenting out the lines that cause the errors. It's not ideal but it will be fine. You obviously won't be able to use the web.config for production purposes though.